# Rake Aborted! Syntax Error:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with the book 'Agile Web Development With Rails 4', I'm a complete beginner and not understanding a few issues.

I just tried the `rake test:models` command

I was given back:

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/********/Desktop/depot/test/models/product_test.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

What does this exactly mean? I've followed the book word for word and have encountered this problem.

Thanks in advance for your helpful answers and thoughts!

Here's the product_test.rb code

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    test "product attributes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
end
```

Comment: Post your `product_test.rb` model code.

Comment: You are missing an `end` statement in `product_test.rb`.

Comment: You are missing an end at the last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 blocks but only one end statement; there needs to be another `end` at the end:

```
require 'test_helper' 

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase   # <== this is the start of the class
  test "product attributes must not be empty" do   # <== this is the start of a block
    product = Product.new assert product.invalid? 
    assert product.errors[:title].any? 
    assert product.errors[:description].any? 
    assert product.errors[:price].any? 
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any? 
  end  # <== this is missing
end  # <== this is the end of the class
```

`class` is the start of one block and the `do` at the end of the `test` line is another.

This type of error always gets reported against the last line of the file because it cannot tell there is a missing `end` until it gets to the end of the file and doesn't find it.

Comment: So the first end, ends the Class/test block and the final end is the end of the overall code? Sorry just want to have an absolute understanding. Thanks Graeme!

Comment: @RubyMax `do block` should have an `end` and you are missing that!

Comment: @RubyMax, yes, you need an `end` for the `class` and also the test block.  You are missing the one at the end of the test block.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `end` for `do` block.Adding it should fix the error.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    test "product attributes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
  end #do end
end #class end
```